# Changing VSS user via command line

Tags: batch-file, visual-sourcesafe

In my working Environment, I need to access multiple VSS database. 
 For Each database , I have different user ID / Password 
 Moreover , I need to download some data on fixed date ( each wednesday morning) 
 I would like to automate this process.
 I found VSS command to download the data from VSS 
 however, I could not find the command to login by specifying srcsafe.ini path of VSS 
 How to switch VSS accounts in single batch file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the VSS environment variables as needed with something like this in your bat file (assuming user has proper VSS permissions).

```
SET SSDIR=\\PutComputerNameHere\FolderNameHere
SET SSUSER=%UserName%
```

Comment: Thanks ... that has resolved issue... got more detail from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181062(v=vs.80).aspx